# MVC 3 - authorization within a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, authorization

It appears to me the authorization filters can only be applied upon Controller or Action level.

Is it possible to use the authorization within a view? Say, in each row of a list view, the administrators will have buttons like edit, delete while a guest user can only read. Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional statements like

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```